# switch between functions with checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to simplify some information on my play-site.

There are two dif. user-types, students and others.
Many places and stores offer a discount to students, and I would therefore make this accessible with a checkbox that changes some of the scripts.
This Is my example (simplifyed as good as i could):

```
<head>
<script TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="script/script_uteplasser.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_student"  onclick="student();"><span>I'm A student!</span></input></form>
(...)
</body>
```

javascript (script_uteplasser):

```
//--------------------SAMFUNDET---------------------
samfundet = "...blablablabla..." + cc_samfundet() + "...blablablabla...";
//----INNGANGSAV. SAMFUNDET----

var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox_student");
function student(){
    if (checkbox1.checked){
    function cc_samfundet(){var d=new Date(); var theDay=d.getDay(); switch (theDay) { case 1: return "Free"; break;  case 2: return "Free"; break;  case 3: return "Free"; break;  case 4: return "Free"; break;  case 5: return "Free"; break;  case 6: return "Free"; break;  case 0: return "Free";}}
    }
    else{
    function cc_samfundet(){var d=new Date(); var theDay=d.getDay(); switch (theDay) { case 1: return "100,-"; break;  case 2: return "100,-"; break;  case 3: return "100,-"; break;  case 4: return "100,-"; break;  case 5: return "100,-"; break;  case 6: return "100,-"; break;  case 0: return "100,-";}}
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------
```

This doesn't kill the script, but isn't returning any information either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't return anything because you're only defining your function(s) in your evaluation. If you add a second pair of parentheses afterwards, it should work how you intend.

That said, this is a really poor design pattern. First of you don't really need to make what you're doing functions here. Second is creating the same named function twice with completely separate logic - that pretty much brakes every good programming principle.

*Update*: Here is something to point you in the right direction,

```
var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox_student");
// Assuming this function should do something else too?
function student() {
    cc_samfundet(checkbox1.checked);
}

var cc_samfundet = function (isStudent) {
    var d = new Date();
    var theDay = d.getDay();
    switch (theDay) {
        case 1:
            return isStudent ? "Free" : "100,-";
            // and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty fresh at this, as you probably have noticed, hehe, the second pair of parentheses didn't work, but a more elegant solution would be preferable, any pointers :)?

Comment: much smoother, took me some time to get the hang off it, but now it works fine, thank you :)!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to redefine function ?

You can check in your function if checkbox is checked. If you want really to redefine function use this code :

```js
//declare your function :
function cc_samfundet () {
    //...
}
//or :
var cc_samfundet2 = function () { /* ... */ };

//redefine your function :
cc_samfundet = function () {
    //...
}
//or with an existing function :
cc_samfundet = cc_samfundet2;
```